# Plotting: `S=sum(1/x*x for x in range (1,n))` vs. `n`

Tags: python, numpy

Equation

[image]

For n=10,

```
S=sum(1.0 / (x * x) for x in range(1, 11))
```

For n=100,

```
S=sum(1.0 / (x * x) for x in range(1, 101))
```

For n=1000,

```
S=sum(1.0 / (x * x) for x in range(1, 1001))
```

Is there a convenient method of plotting/expressing `n` vs. `S` for

```
import numpy as np
n = np.arange(1,1000, step=1)
```

?

Comment: Have you tried Matplotlib? I think it could solve your issue.

Comment: @MSeifert I am stuck on collating values for `S` for each value of `n` without doing it manually

Comment: compute `S = [sum(1.0/(x*x) for x in range(1, ni+1)) for ni in n]`, then plot?

Comment: @pault It worked, thanks so much for responding so quickly. I'm a complete beginner and was struggling with this for a few hours..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an aggregation function for the series. In the case of a sum-series the numpy functions [`np.add.accumulate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html#numpy-ufunc-accumulate) or [`np.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) would work:

```
import numpy as np
n = np.arange(1, 1000)
one_over_n_squared = 1 / n**2  # element-wise calculation of the factors
series = np.add.accumulate(one_over_n_squared)  # accumulate
```

That way you don't have to recalculate all factors for each point you want to plot. That can be significant if you want to plot or calculate more values.

Then to plot it you could use [matplotlibs plot function](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(n, series)
```

[image]

Or if you want it a (tiny) bit fancier with labels and a logarithmic x axis:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(n, series)
plt.xlabel('n')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.ylabel('Series')
```

[image]